# Create a dictionary from two lists in a one-liner

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

From these lists,

```
lst1 = ['a','b','c']
lst2 = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7]]
```

I want to create:

```
{1: 'a', 3: 'b', 6: 'c', 2: 'a', 4: 'b', 7: 'c', 5: 'b'}
```

I can create it using a for loop:

```
d = {}
for l, nums in zip(lst1, lst2):
    for num in nums:
        d[num] = l
```

I figured I need to use map and zip, so I tried,

```
dict(map(lambda x: dict(x), zip(lst2,lst1)))
```

but this gives

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 1; 2 is required.
```

I think the issue is the `lst2` is a list of lists but I just don't know how to proceed.

Comment: list-comprehensionize the for loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Your expected output is different from the output produced by your loop. If you want to get the expected output in a one liner (excluding imports of course), here is one solution.

(i) Building on @mozway's idea of using `itertools.zip_longest` to create zip object of tuples across sublists, use `dict.fromkeys` method to create a dictionary from these tuples and `lst1`,

(ii) Using `map` and a dict comprehension, create a list of dictionaries from (i)

(iii) Using `functools.reduce`, flatten the list to a single dictionary

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from functools import reduce
out = reduce(lambda d, x: {**d, **x}, map(lambda kv: {k:v for k,v in zip(*kv) if k is not None}, dict.fromkeys(zip_longest(*lst2), lst1).items()))
```

Another solution:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, starmap
from functools import reduce
out = dict(reduce(lambda tp, x: tp+tuple(filter(None, x)), zip_longest(*map(dict.items, starmap(dict.fromkeys, zip(lst2, lst1))))))
```

Output:

```
{1: 'a', 3: 'b', 6: 'c', 2: 'a', 4: 'b', 7: 'c', 5: 'b'}
```

Old solution (if order doesn't matter):

As you say, the issue is that `lst1` is a list and `lst2` is a list of lists. We can use another zip to create sublists from `lst1`. Then use `functools.reduce` to flatten the list of dictionaries:

```
from functools import reduce
out = reduce(lambda d, x: {**d, **x}, 
             map(lambda x: dict(zip(x[0], [x[1]]*len(x[0]))), zip(lst2,lst1)))
```

Or using @Tadhg's excellent suggestion to use `itertools.starmap` and `dict.fromkeys` methods, you can also do:

```
from itertools import starmap
out = reduce(lambda d,x: {**d, **x}, starmap(dict.fromkeys, zip(lst2,lst1)))
```

or using `collections.ChainMap` (even simpler):

```
from collections import ChainMap
out = ChainMap(*starmap(dict.fromkeys, zip(lst2,lst1)))
```

Output:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'b', 5: 'b', 6: 'c', 7: 'c'}
```

Comment: instead of `dict(zip(x[0], [x[1]]*len(x[0])))` you can probably use `dict.fromkeys` to give a list of keys and the value for all of them.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen that's an excellent idea. I included it in the answer. But yeah for this question, dict comprehension is the way to go.

Comment: idk, now that I am seeing it you could use `itertools.starmap` instead of the second lambda to get a list/iterator of the partial dictionaries which is useful on its own. Actually you could then use a `ChainMap`, so the full solution could be done with `collections.ChainMap( *itertools.starmap( dict.fromkeys, zip(lst2, lst1)))` which is kind of cool.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean, the order of keys in a dictionary is meaningless unless you specifically pass it to an `OrderedDict`, I hold by the notion that you shouldn't rely on the order of keys otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

use a comprehension:

```
d = {num:l for l, nums in zip(lst1, lst2) for num in nums}
```

since there is a nested loop you need something to expand the second list, it'd be possible with something like `itertools.chain` but much more complicated than just writing out the loops, whether you do it in a comprehension or as you are doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, just a variant with a dictionary comprehension (similar to what already proposed by @Tadhg), but preserving the order of the indices of the sublists:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

out = {k: v for v, *keys in zip_longest(lst1, *lst2)
       for k in keys if k is not None}
```

ouput:

```
{1: 'a', 3: 'a', 6: 'a', 2: 'b', 4: 'b', 7: 'b', 5: 'c'}
```